# How to pass an array to plsql block and return the result set back to php?

Tags: php, oracle, for-loop, plsql

I am trying to pass the $PRODUCT_NUM array to the pl-sql block and then would to execute the stored function for each of the two product num's in the array and send the result set back to php. i am not well familiar with pl-sql and would appreciate some guidance on how to accomplish this ? My intention is to build a REST based web svc that calls the PHP code below after i clean it up. Not sure if i want to create a stored procedure for the below sql block as i expect 1000's of hits for the below code every minute.

```
<?php
 $conn = oci_connect("username","password","localdb");

 $CONFIG_NAME='DirectType';
 $BUS_SEG_CODE='';
 $PRODUCT_NUM=array('130342','270179');
 $MEMBER_NAME='87307-3';
 $EFFECTIVE_DATE=strtotime('2016-12-01');
 $MODEL_DATE=time();
 $CURRENCY='USD';
 $REALM_NUM=1024;
 $RESOLVED_PRICE=111;
 $RESOLVED_CURRENCY='USD';

 if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection Successful"."\n";
    echo "System time is ".time();

    $sql_proc = "
    DECLARE
      v_MEMBER_ID NUMBER;
      v_PRODUCT_ID NUMBER;
      PRODUCTNUMBER NUMBER;
      BASEPRICE NUMBER;
      RESOLVEDPRICE NUMBER;
      UPCHARGEAMOUNT NUMBER;
      CURRENCY VARCHAR2;
      PRICINGDOCNAME VARCHAR2(100);
      TIER_INDEX NUMBER;
      DOC_ID VARCAHR2(100);
   BEGIN
            SELECT cat_map_id INTO v_PRODUCT_ID
            FROM CAT_MAP WHERE product_num IN :PRODUCT_NUM_ARR and catalog_type = 'INT';

            SELECT member_id INTO v_MEMBER_ID
            FROM MEMBER_TABLE WHERE member_name = :MEMBER_NAME;

            v_PMLI_PK :=    PACKAGE.function(:CONFIG_NAME,:BUS_SEG_CODE,v_MEMBER_ID,v_PRODUCT_ID,TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE(:EFFECTIVE_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')),TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE(:MODEL_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')),
                                                             :CURRENCY_CODE,:REALM_NUM,:RESOLVED_PRICE,:RESOLVED_CURRENCY);

       SELECT
            PMLI.PRODUCT_NUM INTO PRODUCTNUMBER,
            PMLI.BASE_PRICE INTO BASEPRICE,
            PMLI.PRICE INTO RESOLVEDPRICE,
            PMLI.UP_CHARGE INTO UPCHARGEAMOUNT,
            PMLI.PRICE_CURR INTO CURRENCY,
            NULL,
            DOC.STRUCT_DOC_NAME INTO PRICINGDOCNAME,
            PMLI.TIER_INDEX INTO TIER_INDEX,
            NULL,
            PMLI.DOC_ID INTO DOC_ID,
            NULL
           FROM P_MASTER PMLI
            INNER JOIN DOC_TABLE DOC
            ON (PMLI.STRUCT_DOC_ID = DOC.STRUCT_DOC_ID)
           WHERE PMLI.PMLI_ID = v_PMLI_PK;

   END;


  $stmt = oci_parse($conn,$sql_proc);
  //  Bind the input parameter

 oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':CONFIG_NAME',$CONFIG_NAME);
 oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':BUS_SEG_CODE',$BUS_SEG_CODE);
 oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':EFFECTIVE_DATE',$EFFECTIVE_DATE);
 oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':MODEL_DATE',$MODEL_DATE);
 oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':CURRENCY_CODE',$CURRENCY);
 oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':REALM_NUM',$REALM_NUM);
 oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':RESOLVED_PRICE',$RESOLVED_PRICE);
 oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':RESOLVED_CURRENCY',$RESOLVED_CURRENCY);

 // Parse the statement. Note there is no final semi-colon in the SQL statement
 $result=oci_execute($stmt);

if (!$result){
    $e = oci_error($stmt);  // For oci_execute errors pass the statement handle
    print htmlentities($e['message']);
    print "\n<pre>\n";
    print htmlentities($e['sqltext']);
    printf("\n%".($e['offset']+1)."s", "^");
    print  "\n</pre>\n";

}
else {
    echo "Execute STMT returns True or False : ".$result;
    echo "Resolved Price is : ".$RESOLVED_PRICE. "\n";
}
echo "</pre>";
oci_free_statement($stmt);
oci_close($conn);
}
else {
$e = oci_error();
trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
  ?>
```

Comment: Please have a look at [mcve] to build a more compact example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions is that you create your SQL block as a stored procedure in your database.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm

Let your procedure accept a parameter, a collection(Table type to be precise).
Create a table type in your database:

```
    CREATE TYPE myRec AS OBJECT (NUMBER(10));
    CREATE TYPE myTab AS TABLE OF myRec;
```

Your procedure must accept a param of type myTab:

```
    PROCEDURE p_myProc(param1 myTab) IS...
```

Then in your php code, simply call this procedure:

```
    $sql_proc = "p_myproc(yourPHPArrayVariable)";
```

Please note that you'll have to make sure the data types are in sync..I mean dont pass characters if your underlying record in database is number as in my example.

Comment: I am building a REST based Web Svc using the php to execute an existing the Oracle Stored Function. So i am not sure if i want to build a stored procedure in the database as i expect about >1000 hits every minute.

Comment: I am pursuing your suggestion. i have given up on executing sql through the OCI interface and fetch the results from the array. It is so much error ridden. What is working for me is bind variables that are returned from the oracle stored function. and i will stick to that !